# Why do required inputs in Vue.js seem to automatically trigger validation in child components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've noticed that when required inputs are present in a child component, inputs without valid default values are automatically highlighted as incorrect on render despite no user action taking place. Expected behavior is that these form inputs would not be highlighted until an invalid submit attempt occurs.

This problem does not exist if these required inputs are present in the root Vue instance.

Why exactly is this happening? Is this a bug, or is there a documented solution to this that I've managed to overlook (apart from third-party input components)?

Below is a minimal example demonstrating the problem.

```js
Vue.component('my-form-component', {
  template: `
    <form>
      <input type="radio" v-model="input_val" name="test" value="0" required/> 0
      <br/>
      <input type="radio" v-model="input_val" name="test" value="0" required/> 1
    </form>
  `,
  data: function() {
    return {
      input_val: ''
    };
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-form-component></my-form-component>
</div>
```

Additionally, this issue is being observed using Firefox and has existed in previous versions of the browser.

Comment: What browser are you testing this on? Can't reproduce on Chrome 63.

Comment: Firefox 57 (earlier versions of Firefox were also problematic).

Comment: Right, happening here on Firefox too (Edge and Chrome work fine). Try posting an issue to https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues, maybe the Vue team can debug it further or submit a technical bug to Firefox.

Comment: On Chrome, if I click the 0 button, it changes the selection to the 1. Is that related to your issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue may be caused by a Firefox bug as noted in [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1399046). Specifically, the issue is that required inputs are being prematurely validated when values are set via JavaScript.

I've added the issue to Vue's issue tracker and was provided the above link. Whether or not this issue ends up being resolved will either be up to Vue to handle the edge case, or Mozilla to handle the issue appropriately.